# Change Outlook default account when application is opened

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016, default-profile

I have 3 different e-mails set up on Outlook, one of them (last added) of hotmail.com server but it isn't the default email account, it's set so by the configuration. But whenever I open the Outlook it goes to the home/inbox of that hotmail.com account instead of the default one. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Go in to Control Panel -> Mail.

Choose Profiles.

In there you can choose to be prompted for which profile to open on start, or choose a default profile.